# How to change active color on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                <div class = "container">
                <a href= "#" class = "navbar-brand">#</a>
                <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                <div class  = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>




.nav navbar-nav navbar-right .active a {
color: yellow;
```

Hi guys I want to change my active color to something else I have tried some fixes i found on stack overflow but it does not work. Please can you guys help me?

Comment: This needs a lot of exṕlanation on what you are talking about...

Comment: Okay if you look at the home button it has a li class="active", so basically my question is how do i make the active class change its CSS properties. I tried the code at the bottom. (obviously closing it and linking correctly to the index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector appears to be incorrect:

```
.nav navbar-nav navbar-right .active a {
    color: yellow;
```

This would match an `<a>` tag that is a child of `*.active` element that is the child of `<navbar-right>` that is the child of `<navbar-nav>` that is a child of `*.nav` element.

Perhaps you are looking for:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right .active a {
```

Which would apply to an `<a>` tag that is the child of an `*.active` element that is the child of a `*.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right` element.

Comment: sorry buddy the problem still remains, does it make a difference whether I view the file locally or do i need to upload via FTP to see this sort of change ?

Comment: Can you look in your devtools and see if your `color: yellow` declaration is being picked up and just overridden by the original bootstrap declaration?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this is a syntax issue in your css. This works in the jsfiddle. does it work in your code?

```css
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right .active a {


  color: yellow;


}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">#</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclosure your CSS in `<style> </style>` tags and close the opening bracket.

Alternatively, you can create a separate file named "main.css", put your style code in there and link to the file inside the HTML `<head> </head>` tags with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

**Solution 1: Inside the HTML file**

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                <div class = "container">
                <a href= "#" class = "navbar-brand">#</a>
                <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                <div class  = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<style>
    .nav navbar-nav navbar-right .active a {
        color: yellow; 
    }
</style>
```

**Solution 2: Creating a CSS file**

Put this HTML into your .html file:

```
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
```

Create a file named main.css, ensure it is placed in the same location as your .html file, and put your code into there. It should look something like this:

```
    .nav navbar-nav navbar-right .active a {
        color: yellow; 
    }
```

Comment: I actually wrapped the css in style tags and linked it correctly i just showed a snippet. Sorry buddy.

Comment: Have you verified that the `main.css` file is being loaded?