# How to change nav link color of the active class in bootstrap 5.1?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Here is part of my code:

```html
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg ps-3 pe-3 ps-sm-5 pe-sm-5">
  <Link className="navbar-brand fw-bold" to={ "/"}><span className='text-white'>E</span> <span className='navbar-text'>Gyülekezet</span></Link>
  <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link to={ "/"} className="nav-link p-0 m-2"> Isten hozott!
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link to={ "/about"} className="nav-link p-0 m-2"> Rólunk
        </Link>
      </li>
```

I've tried all these advices:
[How to change active color on bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840126/how-to-change-active-color-on-bootstrap)

[How to change active link color in bootstrap css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557637/how-to-change-active-link-color-in-bootstrap-css)

[How to change the color of active tab in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701512/how-to-change-the-color-of-active-tab-in-bootstrap)

but they don't work.

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Rendered HTML is better than JSX or whatever, and please include your attempt at a solution. See [ask] and take the [tour].